# Go vs JavaScript JSON parsing

Tags: javascript, node.js, go

Recently, I needed to parse the JSON that the Chrome web browser produces when you record events in its dev tools, and get some timing data out of it. Chrome can produce a pretty large amount of data in a small amount of time, so the Ruby parser I originally built was quite slow.

Since I'm learning Go, I decided to write scripts in both Go and JavaScript/Node and compare them.

The simplest possible form of the JSON file is what I have in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/jclem/5978436#file-data-json). It contains an event representing the request sent to fetch a page, and the event representing the response. Typically, there's a *huge* amount of extra data to sift through. That's its own problem, but not what I'm worried about in this question.

The JavaScript script that I wrote is [here](https://gist.github.com/jclem/5978436#file-parser-js), and the Go program I wrote is [here](https://gist.github.com/jclem/5978436#file-parser-go). This is the first useful thing I've written in Go, so I'm sure it's all sorts of bad. However, one thing I noticed is that it's *much* slower than JavaScript at parsing a large JSON file.

Time with a 119Mb JSON file in Go:

```
$ time ./parse data.json
= 22 Requests
  Min Time:      0.77
  Max Time:      0.77
  Average Time:  0.77
./gm data.json  4.54s user 0.16s system 99% cpu 4.705 total
```

Time with a 119Mb JSON file in JavaScript/Node:

```
$ time node parse.js data.json
= 22 Requests
  Min Time: 0.77
  Max Time: 0.77
  Avg Time: 0.77
node jm.js data.json  1.73s user 0.24s system 100% cpu 1.959 total
```

(The min/max/average times are all identical in this example because I duplicated JSON objects so as to have a very large data set, but that's irrelevant.)

I'm curious if it's just that JavaScript/Node is just way faster at parsing JSON (which wouldn't be particularly surprising, I guess), or if there's something I'm doing totally wrong in the Go program. I'm also just curious what I'm doing wrong in the Go program in general, because I'm sure there's plenty wrong with it.

Note that while these two scripts do more than parsing, it's *definitely* `json.Unmarshal()` in Go that is adding lots of time in the program.

**Update**

I added a [Ruby script](https://gist.github.com/jclem/5978436#file-parse-rb):

```
$ ruby parse.rb
= 22 Requests
  Min Time: 0.77
  Max Time: 0.77
  Avg Time: 0.77
ruby parse.rb  4.82s user 0.82s system 99% cpu 5.658 total
```

Comment: Just as a terminology note, "parsing" is what happens when you call `JSON.parse()` or the Go `json.unMarshal()`.  The rest of the work is just traversal of the resulting data structure.

Comment: @Pointy I'm perfectly aware of this. It's `json.Unmarshal()` in Go that's much slower than `JSON.parse()` in JavaScript (or appears to be). You're right, I should have used a different verb in some places, here. :)

Comment: OK yes I've been reading over your code and those results and now I think I see what you mean.  That's pretty weird; parsing JSON should be crazy fast in *any* language, as the syntax is so dirt-simple. Maybe the differences involve the construction of the data structure (the "actions" of the parse process)?  Or maybe nobody's spent much time optimizing the Go JSON parser :)

Comment: @Pointy FWIW, I added a Ruby version. The Go version is only a second faster, most of the time.

Comment: Well in cases like this, where you have a somewhat fixed "schema" for your JSON data, if you want something fast you can build a special purpose parser that inherently understands important property names. That way you can avoid some redundant string comparisons, because the parser can turn those keywords into simple tokens. Of course, you'd really have to be kind-of desparate to do that.

Comment: It's more of an overall concern with Go's JSON parsing performance that I have. I thought it'd be much faster. Obviously, Node.js's performance is phenomenal here, so I'll be using that for this particular need from now on.

Comment: You have a lot of loops and loop inside loops in your code, and you resize slices in those loops (which can be expensive). So you can’t be sure that Go’s JSON parser is slower than JS’s. Maybe it’s its memory allocation. You better measure times of different parts of your program using `time` package.

Comment: @Mostafa I probably should have cut out all of the extra cruft here, but I ran separate tests where I just unmarshalled into the structs in my Go program (no loops, just parsing), and it was still around the same difference in time.

Comment: @Mostafa See: https://gist.github.com/jclem/5979042

Comment: @clem Now that’s interesting. It’s no wonder that Go’s JSON parser is not the fastest, because it has not been optimized much. But this seems to be too much. You may help in solving this if you post your code and results in [go-nuts mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts).

Comment: What version of Go are you using, out of curiosity?

Comment: [This forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-bugs/IxyyTLHvjQ0) seems relevant as well.

Comment: What happens if you parse the JSON twice in the same instance of the Go process? Most of the slowness is `reflect` figuring out the types. The `encoding/xml` package caches this lookup the first time, and `encoding/json` may work the same way. The second time may be faster than the first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Go, you are parsing the JSON into statically-typed structures. With JS and Ruby, you are parsing it into hash tables.

In order to parse JSON into the structures that you defined, the json package needs to find out the names and types of their fields. To do this, it uses the reflect package, which is much slower than accessing those fields directly.

Depending on what you do with the data after you parse it, the extra parsing time may pay for itself. The Go data structures use less memory than hash tables, and they are much faster to access. So if you do a lot with the data, the savings on processing time may outweigh the extra parsing time.

Answer (score 0):

Default Go JSON parsing is really slow. I benchmarked it with 5M json file.

Go's `encoding/json`:

```
2024/01/07 21:58:47 UnMarshal: 54.60 ms
2024/01/07 21:58:47 Marshal: 13.70 ms
```

NodeJS

```
JSON.parse took 16.12 milliseconds.
JSON.stringify took 30.06 milliseconds.
```

Though, you can use alternative modules in Go lang which provide the same performance as NodeJS.

Go's https://github.com/goccy/go-json

```
2024/01/07 22:06:27 UnMarshal: 17.45 ms
2024/01/07 22:06:27 Marshal: 10.80 ms
```